# One change event for multiple Elements, Run function once

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<label>
  <select id="foo">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>
  <select id="bar">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>
  <select id="foobar">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on("change", "#foo, #bar, #foobar", function(){
    $("#bar").val($("#foo").val()).trigger("change");
  /* Do something for #foo & #bar*/

  /* Run this when all changes are done */
    console.log("done");
})
```

**The issue**
When running the above, i get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` Which i understand, Since the change event repeats indefinitely.

How would one avoid that?
I have common `Change` code for those elements and they all need to run the same function at the end, but only after all `Change` events were triggered.
note: The `.trigger("change")` is required, i oversimplified the code.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v0qjqq4f/17/)

**edit**
added code more similar to what i have.

Comment: Why does the change event repeat indefinitely? is it in a loop? or recursive function?

Comment: @AdamCopley - since `change` is bound to both `#foo` & `#bar`, calling `trigger("change")` on `#bar` re-initiates the `change` event.

Comment: @Dementic Is this one directional? `bar` changes when `foo` changes, but should the opposite happen? I mean in the case `foo` is changed?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan - it is one directional.

Comment: That was going to be my next question ^^, it may not need to be bound to both? if for example the changes happen in a chain. `foo.change -> bar.change -> baz.change`. then you would have a click condition for each, rather than being bound in the same click function

Comment: @AdamCopley - The text boxes are independent, and in RL they are select boxes (3 of them) only when `#foo` changes, `#bar` needs to be changed, but the rest of the code is common to all of them (classes, styles, etc...)

Comment: @Dementic `$("#bar, #baz").val($("#foo").val())` wont this be enough? Is there any special reason why you are triggering change of the second one?

Comment: And how are you populating the select boxes? ajax, and response with options? -  are you changing the value of select(2) to match select (1)  or populating wiht different options based on the value of select(1)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan - no, the trigger is needed because `select2` (in RL) will not show the change without triggering.

Comment: @AdamCopley - selects are populated from ajax source, i do not see how this has any relation to the question.

Comment: Check my answer, I haven't edited it to suit your code but you seem apt enough to understand what's going on.  In short,  onClick I call a js function which accepts the field name and value as parameter, then the ajaxrequest.php file runs a query based on the POST values sent by the js function.

Answer (score 0):

Use one instead of on as follows

```
$(document).one("change", "#foo, #bar", function(){
    $("#bar").val($("#foo").val()).trigger("change");
  /* Do something for #foo & #bar*/

  /* Run this when all changes are done */
    console.log("done");
})
```

Comment: i need the change event to run more then once.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd consider using Javascripts requestAnimationFrame(). It's a bit of a cheat, but will allow you to infinitely check without locking up your browser.

I'd even consider combining part of @Thangaranja's answer with this. For example (swapping 'one' to 'on');

```
function check_changes(){
  $(document).on("change", "#foo, #bar", function(){
    $("#bar").val($("#foo").val()).trigger("change");
    * Do something for #foo & #bar*/

    /* Run this when all changes are done */
    console.log("done");
  })
}

requestAnimationFrame(check_changes);
```

This is an untested idea, but may work for you.

Comment: This is a hack and might work, but there must be a "normal" way to solve such.

Comment: Agreed, it's a little unconventional. I'd also be interested to see if there's a normal way, it wouldn't make much sense if there wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetch new options via ajax I recommend passing the field name and value on to this function like so.  You will need to change the field names however this should make sense.

`onChange="menuChange('fieldname', this.value)"`

```
function menuChange(field, value){


    switch(field){

        case "class":
        document.getElementById("class").options.length = 0;
        document.getElementById("category").options.length = 1;
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options.length = 1;
        break;

        case "category":
        document.getElementById("category").options.length = 0;
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options.length = 1;
        break;

        case "subcategory":
        document.getElementById("subcategory").options.length = 0;
        break;

    }
    document.getElementById(field).options.length = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxrequest.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { field: field,
              value: value },
        success: function (response) {

           console.log(response);
           document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = response;               

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }


    });



}
```

just to put it into imagery:

Group, is populated first, and nothing else is, when group is changed, class is updated with values for group, when class is changed, category is updated witt values for class.........

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the try, but i fail to see how this helps.

Comment: The data is loaded fine, and is in a different handler then this. This is just a UI issue, and not an issue with getting the data.

Comment: it's not about the data, it's about the js function only clearing the values of the next select box in the chain.  the fact that you are using ajax to get data just helps in the usabiity of the js function.  I'll delete the php seeing as it's not that relevant

Comment: using your method will still create the same issue when one change is calling another.

Comment: can you explain further about the desire behaviour of your select boxes, you say they happen in a chain, but is this in the order of.  
`onChange(1)->change2, onChange(2)->change3`  OR
`onChange(1)->change2, change3, change4`

Comment: They DO NOT happen in a chain, but exactly as shown in code. When #Foo is called #Bar is changed, therefor the loop

Comment: So then it `isn't` one directional as you said in the comments on your question?  By the looks of your updated jsfiddle and code, it looks like you want to be able to make changes happen backwards too.  i.e. 1 and 3 update when you change  2.

Again I would recommend passing the clicked field name into a function, which will then have a switch statement which decides which other fields to change.

Comment: nope, its one direction, #foo changes #bar, that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103012/discussion-between-adam-copley-and-dementic).